# Как найти файл по вхождению строки?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно в папке Prefetch найти файл с определенным именем,но я знаю точно вхождение строки в его названии.После того как я его найду,мне нужно его удалить.Как это проще всего сделать?
Я знаю функцию remove,но она принимает в себя полное имя файла,а я не знаю точное имя файла,знаю только несколько символов на которое он начинается

Comment: Перебрать все файлы, проверяя совпадение начала имени.

Comment: Подобные задачи проще решать, используя [system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system)